# Pagerank updated and traffic change, what's first?

Tags: seo, pagerank

As we all know, pagerank is not updated very often, this month it Did.

Thing is in one of my sites google traffic increased about a 300% and then I realised that pagerank improved 1 point,

My question here is a little bit difficult to express,

Basically, Does traffic change is because of the PR change or the PR it's just a reflection of current status?

Answer (score 3):

1. PageRank is *per page* not per website. So your home page PR may have changed but that doesn't mean other pages did as well.
2. That PageRank you update you saw (if there was one) is stale data. It reflects the PR for a page at some arbitrary point in time but now *right now*.
3. PageRank is updated at Google daily if not more frequently. So, just like above, that number you see if already obsolete.
4. PageRank used to play a huge role in Google's ranking algorithm. Nowadays its role is imperceptible. An increase of 1 PR point isn't going to make a big difference for better or worse.

Your increase in traffic from Google can be from lots of things. Check to see if you got new links, etc.

Comment: Hi there, just for curiosity I checked the pagerank for the most viewed pages and it's the same as the homepage, actually; I didn't find any with a different one (of corse I didnt check the 20.000 ones jaja)

Comment: It's possible that your inner pages have the same PR as your home page. The public PR number is rounded so they can be almost 1 PR apart but still reported the same. But I suspect that whatever tool you use is only reporting your home page PR and not your inner page PR as it is uncommon for *every* page to have the same PR.

Comment: Could you suggest a service that you know for sure it returns the different PR? (BTW the current one I have is 3)

Comment: I haven't checked a page's PR is a very long time. I'm not sure what tools or services are reliable. But if you ask in [chat] I know you will get good recommendations.